# The total amount of free network bandwidth an always free compute can use for a month or some period of time

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

From the [Oracle cloud infrastructure always free service document site](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/FreeTier/resourceref.htm), it says this:

> All tenancies get two Always Free Compute virtual machine (VM)
> instances.
>
> You must create the Always Free Compute instances in your home region.
>
> Details of the Always Free Compute instance Shape:
>
> VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro Processor: 1/8th of an OCPU with the ability to
> use additional CPU resources
>
> Memory: 1 GB
>
> Networking: Includes one
> VNIC  with one public IP address and up to 480 Mbps network bandwidth
>
> Operating System: Your choice of one of the following Always
> Free-eligible operating systems:
>
> Oracle Linux (including Oracle Autonomous Linux) Canonical Ubuntu
> Linux CentOS Linux

The **VNIC  with one public IP address and up to 480 Mbps network bandwidth** describes the network speed not the **amount limit** from my point of view. So the question is how much bandwidth one always free compute can use freely for a month or some peroid of time.

Comment: Inbound is free, and outbound is free for the first 10 terabytes. Surprisingly generous. https://www.oracle.com/cloud/networking/networking-pricing.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oracle's [press release for Always Free](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/pressrelease/oow19-oracle-free-tier-091619.html#) launch explicitly mention

> The new Always Free program includes the essentials users need to build and test applications in the cloud: Oracle Autonomous Database, Compute VMs, Block Volumes, Object and Archive Storage, and Load Balancer. Specifications include:
>
> ...
>
> - 1 Load Balancer, 10 Mbps bandwidth
> - 10 TB/month Outbound Data Transfer

Comment: I tested out the speed: Download: 351.00 Mbit/s, Upload: 178.26 Mbit/s